# DropZone implementation with multiple file types + Carrierwave

Tags: activeadmin, carrierwave, dropzone

I have searched a lot for a straightforward way or example to integrate Dropzone into my existing ActiveAdmin application that already uses carrier waves for single file upload

But I'm not able to find any such examples or implementation that helps me to accomplish this.

```
Book Model Class <- Need to upload multiple Files(jpeg/pdf/xls) at once through drag and drop feature
```

Note: Have already looked into dropzone-ativeadmin gem, but there is no example project that helps to accomplish the explanation given for same